# Any legal consequences using existing free product available for everyone

Tags: united-states, intellectual-property, licensing, european-union

First of all, I want to say that my language used in the question might sound vague and incompetent, because it I'm not familiar with legal terminologies even in my native language.

I have an idea and product realization that is it sort of built on existing patent. It is a kit to build Google Cardboard VR. Kit is imprinted on a existing selling product package. Of course, by selling this product I make money. Google Cardboard kit scheme is free on internet for home assembling and manufacturing. I tried to find the licence of the Google Cardboard kit, but failed.

According to which US & EU laws, I'm allowed to incorporate this imprint on the package?

Is there a room for law suit for any kind of infringement, even if I just imprint the scheme and let people fold and assemble it themselves?

Comment: Do you mean you will imprint the Google Cardboard VR kit onto existing product packaging? The box of an iPhone, for example?

Comment: @jimsug Yes, imprint the scheme to existing packaging, so people can cut it and fold it themselves.

Answer (score 1):

You said you couldn't find the license, so copyright is assumed.

By printing it on your packaging, you are distributing their intellectual property without their permission. Furthermore, you are making a profit. That smells like copyright infringement to me, and you are subject to whatever penalties are there, from a Cease & Desist, to monetary compensations.

Fair use [mostly applies](http://fairuse.stanford.edu/overview/fair-use/what-is-fair-use/) to commentary and parody, you can't claim it.

Comment: The cardboard kit is available for *manufacturers* here : https://www.google.com/get/cardboard/manufacturers/

Does the term manufacturer means one that can get the kit cut it and sell it? I can see there are plenty of certified cardboard manufactures and also plenty Chinese sellers across the internet.

Comment: @NikolaDespotoski if they give you explicit permission to use it by yourself, yes. If they don't, or you are unsure, ask them to be on the safe side.

Comment: @NikolaDespotoski in other words, they may have that page public for easy access of their partners, or for you to know what would you get if you become one; or they may be indeed free for you to use. You can't safely assume either way without an explicit note that I haven't found. They do have some registration to join the WWGC program: g.co/joinwwgc